# Which suitable eye drop to choose for computer vision syndrome?

Tags: eye, artificial-tear-eye-drops, medications

Working and chilling using PC over 10h a day, which results in a very uncomfortable eye condition. My eyes are often quite red and I feel "sandpaper" in the eyes. I see a very big variety of eyedrops - which ingredients should eye drops contain to ease my discomfort when I look at a screen for a long time?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). We'd love to help but shopping questions are [voted as off-topic on meta](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/45/are-shopping-questions-off-topic). You might consult your doctor or ask about specific ingredients, but we can't recommend a particular brand. VTC

Comment: @Lucky could one recommend some chemical ingredients for eye drops here so I can choose the brand by myself but knowing what effect I'd like to receive?

Comment: "Ten hours a day" is the actual problem. Human eyes were not evolved to keep the eyes held in position like this for so long. You need to close your eyes after 20 minutes of computer use and wait for the strain to reduce. You also need to get 8 hours of uninterrupted sleep each night. Eye drops won't help much if you don't give your eye muscles rest (intraocular and extraocular).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Bausch & Lomb Computer Eye Drops provide moisture for dry and irritated eyes. The fast-acting soothing effect eliminates eye discomfort. Bausch & Lomb Computer Eye Drops provide relief from exposure to prolong computer use that can irritate eyes.

Directions
•instill 1 or 2 drops in the affected eye(s) as needed

Warnings

Do not use if solution changes color or becomes cloudy

When using this product:
•do not touch tip of container to any surface to avoid contamination
•remove contact lenses before using
•replace cap after use

Stop using and ask a doctor if:
•you experience eye pain, changes in vision, continued redness or irritation of the eye condition worsens or persists for more then 72 hours

For more information on other ways of eliminating computer eye strain other than using eye drops, visit:

http://visionsource.com/blog/tips-for-eliminating-computer-eye-strain/